type error: installing odoo 16 on ubuntu 18.04
I am installing odoo 16 on ubuntu 18.0 desktop version. I updated and upgraded ubuntu. I am getting this error message when I run this command:
sudo git clone https://www.github.com/odoo/odoo --depth 1 --branch=16.0 --single-branch

error message:
error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed

I tried to increase the postBuffer from the default 1MB by using this command:
git config http.postBuffer 524288000DD


Don't throw sudo around for no reason. Also, what are you doing with Ubuntu 18.04 in 2024? There have been three LTS releases since then: 20.04, 22.04, and now 24.04. 18.04 has been completely unsupported for a year and a half.

Try cloning through ssh - git clone git@github.com:odoo/odoo.git ....
In order to do so you need to have ssh key, you can follow the guide - generating a new ssh key
Another point that might help is when you config buffer size, use --global, not sure if it would help, but it won't hurt.

I tried the command but i am getting this error.Cloning into 'odoo'...
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Updating my answer with follow up answer

You can try cloning through the following command:
git clone --depth 1 --branch 16.0 github.com/odoo/odoo.git --single-branch

